# Can't get data from controller with ajax request

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, laravel, eloquent

Trying to get `products` from `productController` with `category_id`

As seen blow. Codes are basic ajax request codes, there is no complicated things. But my result is allways null.

**ROUTE**

```
Route::post('urun-listele', 'ProductController@listele');
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function listele(Request $request)
{

    $category_id = $request['category_id'];
    $urunler = Product::where('category_id', $category_id)->get();

    #var_dump($urunler);
    return json_encode([
        'urunler' => $urunler
    ], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

**AJAX**

```
function urunListele(kategori_id) {

    var kapsayici = $('#product-info');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'urun-listele',
        type: "POST",
        data: {category_id: kategori_id},
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var urunler = data['urunler'];

            for (var i = 0; i < urunler.length; i++) {
                kapsayici.append('<div class="col-md-3 product-detail-item b-white br-10px"><p>' + urunler[i]['title'] + '</p></div>');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

As i said, can't get any data.

```
var urunler = data['urunler'];

        for (var i = 0; i < urunler.length; i++) {
            kapsayici.append('<div class="col-md-3 product-detail-item b-white br-10px"><p>' + urunler[i]['title'] + '</p></div>');
        }
```

`console.log(urunler);` allways return 0 object. Where is the problem? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

i got `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` when try return $urunler;

`$category_id = $request['category_id'];` can't get anything i think.
For example if i change `$category_id = 5` it `return [object Object],[object Object]`
i have 2 object with `$category_id = 5`. 
is problem here? `$category_id = $request['category_id'];`

EDIT2:

```
$category_id = $request->get('category_id');
    $urunler = Product::whereCategoryId($category_id)->get();

    return response()->json([
        'urunler' => $urunler
    ]);
```

Controller changed like this and its working right now.

Comment: have you checked or print your query?

Comment: yes do what @AmitRajput Said

Comment: query returning null. Can't get any data.

Comment: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)

Comment: @AliÖzen Are you sure there are products with that `category_id`? And what happens if you change `$category_id = $request['category_id']` into `$category_id = $request->input('category_id')`?

Comment: yes i am sure. It is return null too.

Comment: Please show your **Product** Model also.

Comment: You don't need to use json_encode to return the json response. You can use the laravel default response json method. `return response()->json([
    'name' => 'Abigail',
    'state' => 'CA'
]);`

Comment: @SumitParkash yes. I figured it out and solve the problem. As i wrote in edit section. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to a number of reasons first I am not sure if this is the correct syntax `$request['category_id'];`, but I may be wrong. I use most of the time `$request->category_id.

Second could you tell us wethere there is actual data here:

`$category_id = $request['category_id'];`

`$urunler = Product::where('category_id', $category_id)->get();`

Just `dd($category_id)` and `dd($urunler)` and tell us the results.

Furthermore you have a success method in your ajax request but not an error method could you add one and give us the results aswell?

Do something like this after your success function:

```
error: function(response) {
    console.log(response) // this should hold a nice error message
}
```

Thus be sure that you actually post data in your ajax post, just `console.log` this `kategori_id`

At last laravel already returns a json by default so you do not actually need to do this, only if there is further reason for it.

You could replace this:
    `return json_encode([
        'urunler' => $urunler
    ], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

With this:

`return $urunler;`